# Hola como cambiar dentro de una macro la ruta del archivo sobre la cual se desarrolla esta macro teniendo la ruta en una celda

Tags: excel

```
Sub EQUIPOS()

    Dim wbLibroOrigen As Workbook
    Dim wsHojaOrigen As Worksheet
    Dim wbLibroDestino As Workbook
    Dim wsHojaDestino As Worksheet
    Dim Ruta As String
    
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'INGRESAR RUTA DEL ARCHIVO ORIGEN (Cambiar _Mes_Año)O COPIAR NOMBRE DESDE PROPIEDADES DE ARCHIVO
    
    Ruta = "C:\Users\Desktop\Consolidado 2020-2023\control Diciembre 2020\DATA EQUIPOS DICIEMBRE-2020.xlsm"
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'ABAJO PARTE DEL CODIGO VBA DE TRABAJO.... COMO EJEMPLO
    
    Set wbLibroDestino = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
    Set wsHojaDestino = wbLibroDestino.Worksheets("RENTAL_PAD_1")
    
    Set wbLibroOrigen = Workbooks.Open(Ruta)
    Set wsHojaOrigen = wbLibroOrigen.Worksheets("RENTAL_PAD_1")
    
    uFila = wsHojaOrigen.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    wsHojaOrigen.Range("A15:AN" & uFila).Copy Destination:=wsHojaDestino.Range("A15")
    
    Workbooks(wbLibroOrigen.Name).Close Savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema? tu pregunta es solo un monton de codigo sin ningun problema planteado...

Comment: El código muestra la ruta, básicamente esta ruta se debe cambiar cada mes pero no podemos dar acceso al interior de la macro a los usuarios para cambiar la ruta cada mes dentro de la macro. Es posible dentro de esta macro que ella  cambie la ruta desde un valor externo (Celda excel) , Gracias

Comment: Por supuesto.. y cual es el problema?

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto, no conozco los codigos para desarrollar esto, agradezco tu colaboracion

Answer (score 1):

en tu código tienes:

```
 Ruta = "C:\Users\Desktop\Consolidado 2020-2023\control Diciembre 2020\DATA EQUIPOS DICIEMBRE-2020.xlsm"
```

Suponiendo que la ruta del archivo estuviera en la celda A1 de una hoja que tiene de nombre HOJA1, modifica la línea y prueba así:

```
 Ruta = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HOJA1").Range("A1").Value
```

Es muy importante que el nombre de la hoja y la referencia de la celda esté bien escrito.

Prueba así y nos cuentas.